# Windows command line tar "cannot connect to d: resolve failed" with Chef Knife

Tags: command-line, gzip, tar, chef-infra

Using Windows Command line with cygwin, chef and ruby installed.  When trying

```
knife cookbook site install mysql
```

returns the following error

```
Begin output of tar zxvf D:/path/to/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql.tar.gz  
STDOUT:  
STDERR: tar<child>: Cannot connect to D: resolve failed  
gzip: stdin: undexpected end of file  
tar: Child returned status 128  
tar:  Error is not recoverable: exiting now</code>
```

How can I remedy this issue?  I can manually unzip using

```
tar zxvf mysql.tar.gz
```

but this is less than ideal.  I believe this has to do with the [colon in filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13377/tar-extraction-depends-on-filename) but how can I change that in the knife or chef preferences?

Answer (score 45):

The reason is that `tar` interprets colons (`:`) in file names as meaning it is a file on another machine. You can disable this behavior by using the flag `--force-local`.

This is from an answer from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13381/146563).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a complete answer but have been seeing this on Linux machines lately:

```
$ date > today
$ tar -czf - today > to:day.tgz
$ tar -tzf to:day.tgz
ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
tar (child): to\:day.tgz: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
$ tar -tzf - < to:day.tgz 
today
$
```

It appears that `tar` wants to do some sort of remote file processing because of the colon in the file name and you can fake it out by using some form of redirection or piping - for both reading and writing a tarball.  I would still like to find an option or something to tell `tar` not to behave this way.

Answer (score -1):

Will the tar command work if ran from cmd? Also what if the output is to a local drive. Something else try this,

```
tar zxvf "D:/path/to/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql.tar.gz"
```