# Cannot install gems (tar: Cannot connect to C: resolve failed)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, git-bash

When attempting to install a gem, but I am getting this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>gem install sqlint
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlint:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg_query-0.9.2/ext/pg_query
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170810-19576-j7fs2b.rb extconf.rb
tar: Cannot connect to C: resolve failed
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:22:in `<main>': ERROR (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg_query-0.9.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/pg_query-0.9.2/gem_make.out
```

I can tell from the below post that it has something to do with `tar` not liking `:` in local path names. (mistakes them for remote path names, and fails to connect)

[Windows command line tar "cannot connect to d: resolve failed" with Chef Knife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823499/windows-command-line-tar-cannot-connect-to-d-resolve-failed-with-chef-knife)

However, the answers given there don't help with fixing `gem`. It does appear to install correctly if I follow the entire dependency tree downloading from [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org) and installing each individual component (dependencies first). But that would be a painfully slow process to try and do that every time I want to install 1 gem.

**My Question:** How can I install a gem on Windows without it mistaking the local paths for remote paths?

---

**Additional Info:**

- Git Bash is installed with linux equivalents overriding Windows commands by default. (not sure how to revert this at the moment, so I am unsure if this is a factor)
- Gem Version: 2.6.12
- Ruby Version: 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x64-mingw32]
- I am using Windows 10 Home

Comment: You'll need the development headers for the Posgtres library.

Comment: Ok, how do I get those?

Comment: As a note this is quite an expedition on Windows where compiling from source is not a cultural convention. It might be easier with the Windows 10 "Creators Edition" Ubuntu on Windows support, or via [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) running a Linux VM where these things are taken for granted. The [Postgres source](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/) is available as a download, but it might not be convenient to get.

Comment: Is it a file I can configure in linux and then transfer to windows? I need gems to run in the windows environment.

Comment: The [Creators Update](https://devtidbits.com/2017/06/08/run-ubuntu-16-04-on-windows-10-creators-update/) option for "Windows Subsystem for Linux" should make this whole ordeal a lot more tolerable since Ubuntu has packages for everything you need. If you can get that working it could be pretty seamless. Unfortunately without that package there's no way for Windows to run Linux binaries.

Comment: it looks like this person had the same issue. https://github.com/purcell/sqlint/issues/5, they thought this gist might help https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88.

Comment: Was able to update ruby but the issue still persists after updating

Comment: @tadman Attempted to install gems via that method and ran into this issue: https://pastebin.com/hm8DVnf2